# ReferenceError when loading google map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

When loading the map in a page I get an [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google global code (foundation.js, line 21)

I am not a code expert so if anyone could show me where the issue is it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:

JavaScript

```
function makeMap() {
    var snazzyMap = JSON.parse(wpGlobals.mapOptions);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(13.72638, 100.54029),
        zoom : 15,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        styles : snazzyMap
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(13.72638, 100.54029)
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', makeMap);
```

PHP

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');

function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false', array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/foundation.js', array('google-maps'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('script', 'wpGlobals', array(
        'mapOptions' = > file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/google_map_style.json')
        )
    );
}
```

JSON

```
[{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#b8d4a4"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station.rail","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"gamma":"1"},{"lightness":"0"},{"saturation":"0"}]},{"featureType":"transit.station.rail","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#8490c8"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
```

CSS

```
#map {
    width: 580px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Is the maps API loaded? Look in your javascript console, network tab and see if the google maps script is loaded.

Comment: The maps is showing on the page so I guess the API is loaded. When looking at the consol it seems loaded. Here is the link in case that helps: [link](http://www.ceerd.net/contact_demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your html file inside body tag, `http://www.ceerd.net/wp-content/themes/ceerd/js/foundation.js` file is added twice once at line **293** and once at **300**. And in between that you have added google map script `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;sensor=false` which is causing the issue `Can't find variable: google`.

**Reason** - The first inclusion of foundation.js is using google object, but its not available till then. Since google script is not loaded.

Kindly include **foundation.js** file after including the *google map script*.

Comment: Where exactly is the file foundation.js being added twice? No sure I get it. I looked into foundation.js  lines 293 and 300 and don't see what you say. Could you be more specific as I am not a programmer? Thank you.

Comment: Open your link in chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+I, it will open the inspector. In that you search for "foundation.js. 
Inside body tag you'll find out that, foundation.js script is added twice.

Comment: You don't have to see inside foundation.js for the line numbers.

Comment: Ok got it thank you. The only thing is that the html code is generated so I'm not really sure at what stage the foundation.js is added for the first time. I just know where it is added for the second time as I did that and it's on the functions.php file.

Comment: Then you need to figure out that. Also, I can't see in any php file on your site

Comment: Thank you. The double foundation.js call was indeed the problem. No ReferenceError anymore.